# Priming when transfering to a second carboy

Tags: carbonation, bottle-conditioning

What is the ration of sugar to water for conditioning. For 2 Gallons and 5 Gallons(ie: 1/4 cup sugar to water).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One pound of table sugar will raise the ABV between 1.036 and 1.046 gravity points per gallon, or 1.007 to 1.009 per 5 gallons. Mixing the solution with a ratio of 1 part sugar to 1 part water. The idea is to dissolve the sugar without adding a lot of extra water to the beer.

Comment: Should I add the amount of sugar directly into the Wort, or make a simple syrup? Thank You in advance.

Comment: Make a simple syrup and wait for it to cool to room temp. Put the syrup into the secondary carboy before transferring the beer to the secondary. Doing it in this order will allow the sugar and beer.  Otherwise, if you stir the mixture into the beer it could introduce oxygen and cause issues with the fermentation.